# How to compose an Observable with Before/After behavior

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Assume I have an Observable, and it will emit at most 1 element.

I'd like to do something before and after the element emitting.
How am I suppose to do with operators to compose a new Observable?

Say I want to trace my Observable in below sequence:

1. log starting timestamp (span.start())
2. do real biz to emit element.
3. log ending timestamp (span.finish())

for "after", maybe I can use doOnComplete and doOnError
but I have no idea on how to do "before"

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here's 1 way I can come up with, not sure if it's the best way or there's any potential issues:

```
Future<String> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
  return "Do Biz";
});

Observable<String> original = Observable.from(f).doOnCompleted(() -> {
  System.out.println("inner after");
});
Observable<String> decorated = Observable.defer(() -> {
  System.out.println("Before");
  return original;
}).doOnCompleted(() -> {
  System.out.println("outer after");
});

decorated.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Thanks

Leon

Comment: Is creating your own Callback interface difficult for your project? Doing this, you might get the perfect fit callback of what you want.

Comment: Say the original Observable is created by A, and B wants to decorate it with some logic and create a new Observable. B can't change A's code.

Comment: But if A’s Observable is not final, you can override the callback methods and add add new logic. For example, override start method and add before logic and call super.start()?

Comment: as an aside... it appears you're just getting familiar with RxJava's reactive types. getting familiar with the `Observable` type is a great starting point, and once you're comfortable with its semantics do look at the other types. for example, given the description that the source "will emit at most 1 element", `Single` might express the design intention more clearly than `Observable` (if that part of the design is under your control).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, a cleaner way to do this would be to use `doOnSubscribe` like this:

```java
Observable<String> createInitialObservable() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Execution...");
        return "Do Biz";
    });
}

Observable<String> decorateObservable(Observable<String> source) {
    return source
            .doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println("Before execution"))
            .doOnNext((item) -> System.out.println("Received item '" + item + "'"))
            .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("After execution"));
}

void test() {
    Observable<String> source = createInitialObservable();
    decorateObservable(source)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

The output would be:

```
Before execution
Execution...
Received item 'Do Biz'
Do Biz
After execution
```

However, your solution is completely valid and will get the job done. It's just that in my opinion having a separate place for a callback before execution is a more convenient option.

Comment: Cool! I think this is exactly I  want, Thanks a lot!